# How To Get Cell Value into Matrix Table in Excel

Tags: excel

I am totally new of using advance for data processing in excel. So, I hope anyone here willing to help with this problem.

I have a data table like the table below, which is consist of ID that refer to a Name. Each ID is having a Date value, and grouped by group number in the first column of table.

```
>     GROUP ID  NAME    DATE
>     223   4   DEXY    02/03/2019
>     223   2   CLARKE  03/04/2019
>     223   3   ANDY    09/09/2018
>     223   1   DAVE    07/06/2019
>     224   1   DAVE    01/08/2019
>     224   2   CLARKE  03/03/2014
>     224   4   DEXY    04/05/2019
>     224   3   ANDY    08/06/2019
>     225   4   DEXY    01/05/2019
>     225   3   ANDY    03/03/2014
>     225   1   DAVE    12/08/2019
>     225   2   CLARKE  18/10/2019
>     226   1   DAVE    24/12/2019
>     226   2   CLARKE  29/02/2020
>     226   4   DEXY    06/05/2020
```

[image]

What I wanna do is automatically get the value of Date based on Group Number and ID number that placed horizontally. I have tried using vlookup but I have no idea how to use it properly in this case. My final table has to be like this.

[image]

In my real data, i have to process 2399 of groups number like that. I will really appreciate if anyone could help me solve this problem, Thank you.

Comment: Just to avoid confusion, can you show what your completed table will look like :)

Comment: I believe yoe looking for `INDEX` & `MATCH`

Comment: @urdearboy okey, i've updated hows my table should be. Btw, could you elaborate more about 'index' & 'match' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the output your looking for?

[image]

This is a pivot table (row=Group, Column=ID, value =SUM(Date) -- remember to format as a date), no totals.

I noticed the date format is different. when I corrected for the dates, my output became:

[image]

The assumption here, though, is that each group has one and only one of the expected id's.

Here is a sample with a group, id's, and names, but no dates:

[image]

Comment: thank you @Jbowman, this is actually so simple and definitely works. haha.

Comment: hey @Jbowman, i have a question, how if i have a bunch of group reference that some of them is not associated with any date from source table and i still want to show it anyway. The purpose is to help me determine how many groups is having no data. Just like when we use hlookup or vlookup, we still able to see  if there's some data that doesn't match with reference table. thankyou

Comment: see edited answer above.... if this is incorrect, please update the question or post a new question, with a sample of the data, and expected results.